# Outlook new message size nearly 1mb

Tags: outlook-2010

I've been using Outlook 2010 for several weeks with no issues. 
Suddently, a few days ago, the size of my outgoing messages got huge.
Looking at thsi it appeas that a huge CSS style is beign created with around 14,000 definition for list items, making the message almost 1mb before I even typed in one word.

Emails before that point were very small.

Needless to say I can't remember changing anything, nor can anyone around here provide any possible explanation...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nice bug from MS. See related article: http://news.softpedia.com/news/Office-Outlook-2010-Beta-Message-Size-Fix-Available-134782.shtml

Comment: The Outlook 2010 Beta bug which the updates are designed to fix is related to the usage of number and bullet lists. Apparently, in the Beta development milestone of the Office 2010 email client, the integration of number and bullet lists in a message can cause redundant CSS definitions to also become a part of the outgoing message, increasing its size.

Comment: Fixes to correct the bug are within the article but will only work on NEW messages, not old already affected ones.